# how can i embed trading view widget ticker tape on my ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to embed the trading view widget tiker tape in my ejs file but is not working on the ejs file but when i use it on my normal html file it works, please what am i doing wrong
this is how am embedding it. am a newbiew

```
                <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
  {
    "symbols": [
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "COINBASE:BTCUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "COINBASE:ETHUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "COINBASE:USDTUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "BITFINEX:XRPUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "COINBASE:SHIBUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "NASDAQ:AAPL"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "NASDAQ:TSLA"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "NASDAQ:AMZN"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "FX:EURUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "FX:GBPUSD"
        },
        {
        "description": "",
        "proName": "OANDA:EURUSD"
        }
    ],
    "showSymbolLogo": true,
    "colorTheme": "dark",
    "isTransparent": true,
    "displayMode": "adaptive",
    "locale": "en"
  }
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

can someone please guide me on how i can do it using ejs. it shows on my html but not showing on my ejs file